# API returns NULL response sometimes

Tags: php, json, rest, api, curl

I am making a API request in my web app which looks like this:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://******.com/jdconnectionpool/view? 
requestAction=JOB_FILE_DETAILS&job_no=7476709",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"accept: application/json",
"cache-control: no-cache" 
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo $response;
}
```

Everything looks to be fine. However, it returns `null` **sometimes** for the same set of params on calling multiple times. I do not seem to find any pattern either. Any far fetched information from someone who has experienced this phenomenon would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` as `false` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` as `false` and see if you get proper response everytime. This isn't a recommended approach, however, you could use this to debug whether issue is at your end or their end.

Comment: @vivek_23 what if they forget to remove it? Download cacert from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html abd install it in your web server as a proper solution if at all this is your problem. I would not recommend to switch the SSL verification off even if just to debug.